# Meaning 'people who will bear watching' in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> "The urge of sex has been grossly misunderstood, slandered, and burlesqued by the ignorant and the evil minded, for so long that the very word sex is seldom used in polite society. Men and women who are known to be blessed - yes, BLESSED - with highly sexed natures, are usually looked upon as being **people who will bear watching**. Instead of being called blessed, they are usually called cursed."

Source: *Think and Grow Rich* (book by Napoleon Hill)

What does 'people who will bear watching' mean in this context?

Comment: people who will bear watching = people who are worthy to be watched (because they are dangerous, interesting, weird etc)

Comment: The relevant definition, BTW, is [verb 3c: to call for as suitable or essential](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bear).  It's a hard definition to find if you don't know what you're looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"who will bear watching" is a way of saying "of whom you should be suspicious or circumspect".

You should "keep an eye" on such people and be wary of them.